# I’m right 4 times

Tags: riddle, mathematics

I can be a 2, or a 4. 
Split me in half and I can become a 6, but do it wrongly and I’ll be an 8. 
Lengthen my sides and I am not myself. anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a

> Square?

I can be a 2, or a 4.

> A square can be described as a power of *2* otherwise it's a quadrilateral, *4* sides.

Split me in half and I can become a 6, but do it wrongly and I’ll be an 8.

> Split it in half along the diagonal it becomes two triangles (a *6*). But do it otherwise it'll be two quadrilaterals (an *8*)

Lengthen my sides and I am not myself. anymore.

> If you lengthen the sides of a square it's not a square anymore (assuming you didn't lengthen all four sides equally)

Title

> A square has 4 right angles

Comment: Wow! That was a lot quicker than I expected!

Comment: Also, just a note: the answer is a part of the riddle, so I’ll accept the answer when you explain it.

Comment: @Buzzyy Ok.., so there's more to it than the answer itself?

Comment: Correct! Well done!

Comment: @Buzzyy Do you mean the title is a part of the riddle?

Comment: @Iceman76 Yes, I did